# Issue in IE to change height dynamically of relative position div on slideDown() jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made HTML page with CSS and Jquery.
I have meake one Div(div id is "content") which is wrapped  one div(div id is "content-holder") using below code in $(document).ready() event

```
$('#content').wrap('<div id="content_holder"></div>');
```

I have applied below CSS

```
#content_holder {
    clear:both; 
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:#f5f5f5 url(../images/bg_content.jpg) repeat-x bottom; 
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;   
    position:relative; top:-4px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

also i have made multiple div in div id "content" which is hidden and I am calling slideDown() jquery on radio button click event to display hidden div.

It works fine in all browser except IE. because IE not change main div(id="content-holder") height. So how can I fix this in IE

**Extra HTML Body code**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">  
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">                                  
            <h2 class="pagetitle">Campaign Bid</h2>
                <div id="iPhoneAppControls" class="hide">                   
                    <form name="campaignBIDFrm" id="campaignBIDFrm" action="" class="frmAdvertisers" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h3 class="fieldsetTitle">Select Ad Type</h3>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <fieldset id="campaignAdType"  class="my_custom">
                        <div id="message" class="message"></div>  
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="ad_type" value="text"  />Text(Create standerd 35 character text Ad)</label>
                             <label><input type="radio"  name="ad_type" value="image"  />Image Ad (Create a banner ad by uploading stooprted formats)</label>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="campaignTextAd"  class="tab_content">
                        <h3 class="fieldsetTitle">Text Ad</h3>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <div id="text_ad_message" class="message"></div>    
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <b>Ad Information</b>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Ad Name</label><input type="text" name="text_add_info" value="" class="large" /></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Redirect URL</label><input type="text" name="text_url" value="" class="large"/></p>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <b>Creative</b>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Ad Text</label><input type="text" name="text_add_text" value="" class="large" maxlength="35"/></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Text with Image Ad</label>
                             <select name="tile_ad">
                                 <option value="No">No</option>
                                 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                             </select>
                             </p>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="campaignImageAd"  class="tab_content">
                        <h3 class="fieldsetTitle">Image Ad</h3>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <div id="image_ad_message" class="message"></div>    
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <b>Ad Information</b>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Ad Name</label><input type="text" name="image_add_info" value="" class="large"/></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Redirect URL</label><input type="text" name="image_add_url" value="" class="large"/></p>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                         <b>Creative</b>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Large</label><input type="file" name="img_large" id="img_large"/><input type="hidden" name="file_large" value="" /></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label></label><a class="image-preview" style="width:300px; height:45px;" id="large_preview">Image Size Preview </a></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Medium </label><input type="file" name="img_medium" id="img_medium"/><input type="hidden" name="file_medium" value="" /></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label></label><a class="image-preview" style="width:216px; height:32px;" id="medium_preview">Image Size Preview</a></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Short</label><input type="file" name="img_short" id="img_short"/><input type="hidden" name="file_short" value=""/></p>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label></label><a class="image-preview" style="width:120px; height:18px;font-size:8px;" id="short_preview">Image Size Preview</a></p>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="campaignImageAd">
                        <h3 class="fieldsetTitle">Bid</h3>
                         <div class="spacer"></div>
                             <p class="fullWidth"><label>Bidding($)</label><input type="text" name="bidding" value="" class="validate[required,min[0.05],500]]"/></p>
                       </fieldset>
                        <div class="frmActions">
                            <input name="btnContinue" type="submit" value="Continue" class="button_rounded" /><input name="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button_rounded" />
                        </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>                             
        </div>        
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').wrap('<div id="content_holder"></div>');
    $('#footer').wrap('<div id="footer_holder"></div>');
    $(".hide").css("display","none");
    $("input:radio").css("width","15px");
    $("input:radio").addClass('radioButton');
    $("input:checkbox").css("width","15px");
    $("#iPhoneAppControls").css("display","block");
    $('form').each(function(){
        var form_name=$(this).attr('name');
        $('input, textarea').each(function(){

            var class_name=$(this).attr('class')+"";
            class_arr=class_name.split(" ");
            if(!in_array("colorSelector", class_arr) && $(this).attr('id')=="")
            {
                $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('name')+"_"+form_name);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#content_holder, .message').corner(settings);
    $('#advertiser, #publisher').corner({
        tl: { radius: 5 },
        tr: { radius: 5 },
        bl: { radius: 0 },
        br: { radius: 0 }
    });
    $('#advertiser ul li, #publisher ul li').corner({
        tl: { radius: 3 },
        tr: { radius: 3 },
        bl: { radius: 0 },
        br: { radius: 0 },
        validTags: ["li"]
    });
    $('.infotab').corner(settings1);
    $('.large_graph, .small_graph').corner();
    $('.message').hide(0);
    $('#campaign_breadcrumb ul li span').first().css('margin-left', '0px');
    $(".button_rounded").wrap('<span class="btnLeftCrnr"></span>');

    $('#file_smart_phone_div').hide();
    $('#file_iPad_div').hide();
    $('#tileDiv').hide();
    $('.tab_content').hide();
    $('input[name="ad_type"]').click(function(){
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        jQuery('body').validationEngine('hideAll');
        var ad_type =$('input[name="ad_type"]:checked').val();
        if(ad_type=="text") $('#campaignTextAd').show("fast");
        else if (ad_type=="image") $('#campaignImageAd').show("fast");
    });

});
```

**Necessary CSS Code**

```
#wrapper {
    float:left; width:100%; height:100%;
}
#container {
    width:1002px; margin:0px auto;
}
#container_login {
    width:400px; margin:0px auto;
}
#content_holder {
    clear:both; 
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:#f5f5f5 url(../images/bg_content.jpg) repeat-x bottom; 
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;   
    position:relative; top:-4px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
#content_login_holder {
    clear:both; width:400px; height:290px; margin:0px auto; background:#f5f5f5 url(../images/bg_content.jpg) repeat-x bottom; border:1px solid #d3d3d3; 
    position:relative; top:-4px;
}
#footer_holder{
    clear:both; width:100%; float:left; background:url(../images/bg_footer.jpg) repeat-x top; margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Please give me usefull hints.. because it very important for me.. i am struggling in this issue from long time...

Thanks in advance

From 
Haresh Vidja

Comment: What kind of CSS do you have on the `<div>`'s inside `<div id="content">`.  Also, could you give us a link or create an example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have not uploaded code on server.. i have also mentioned CSS on my question.. thanks

Comment: But there still isn't enough to go on, as shown by the lack of responses on a site chalk full of jQuery/CSS/HTML masters.  If you created a simple, working example that illustrated the problem, you'd have an answer in about 30 seconds.

Comment: I can understand you, but this page contains thousand of line code in HTML page also CSS contains too much code...

Comment: I have added more code for more clarification.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i cant see the height defined in your css. add a hight value.

its and old IE prob, if the hight is not defined,other browsers can see but not IE

Comment: I have not height defined.. but when i call slidDown() jquery for sub div then height automatically increase in case of height not define...

But main issue is here in relative position of main div ie8 is not support to change height in relative positioned div.. so can we fix this?